# PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='order.market', read_only=True) gives an AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class ClientTransaction(model.Models):
    order = models.ForeignKey('main.Order', related_name='client_transaction', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

class Order(BaseModel):
    market = models.ForeignKey('main.Market', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='order')
```

serializers.py

```
class ClientTransactionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    market = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='order.market', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ClientTransaction
        fields=['market']
```

Giving an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'market'

django==2, djangorestframework=>3.7.1

[full error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F16a6.png)

Comment: Do you try get market from not initialized order?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your serializer for getting data from ForeignKey field. In described situation you try to get not initialized order.
Try to use SerializerMethodField for handling this error. For example:

```
class ClientTransactionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    market = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_market(self, obj):
        return obj.order.market if obj.order else None

    class Meta:
        model = ClientTransaction
        fields=['market']
```